# git clone error : fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side

Tags: git, github

I am having read/write access to a git repo but when I try to git clone I am getting the following error:

```
x@ubuntu:~/temp$ git clone git@github.com:Corp/app.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/x/temp/app/.git/
remote: error: Could not read 987324d3bf2dfbbfaf538978aa71521f20567a8
remote: fatal: Failed to traverse parents of commit 09637dac56d440b0e079b0504dbeef3c78815379
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
x@ubuntu:~/temp$
```

What could be the problem? How to confirm remote repo is really corrupt?

Comment: I was going to say run `git fsck` on the remote, but it's on Github... so have you talked to Github support?

Comment: No.. I will try that, but isn't there anything that I could do from my machine locally?

Comment: This was a temporary issue, but it could occur again in the future. I think this question is worth keeping as a reference. @gre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be due to a temporary issue on GitHub side, as it was the case in this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/gma/nesta/issues/23).

The [GitHub site status page](http://status.github.com/) reported such an issue 5 days ago. Maybe your repo suffers from a side-effect of that incident?

In the meantime, check if you cannot load an **archive** from this repository: see "    [All of your downloads. One big button.](https://github.com/blog/729-all-of-your-downloads-one-big-button)"

[image: download button]

That won't give you a repo, but at least an image of the project form which you can work from.